# WooCommerce Subscriptions - Only Allow user one active subscription

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am in the process of building a membership / subscription based site for a client of mine and we are using [Woocommerce Subscriptions](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions) and [Woocommerce Memberships](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-memberships/) plugin.

Now the problem is the my client is building a few promo pages which basically allows the user to purchase an upgrade. This is fine but my client only wants one unique subscription by customer *(with its associated membership)*.

So the agreed solution is that, on a purchase of any new subscription product, all other subscriptions should be cancelled. All associated membership deleted/cancelled and only the latest subscription should remain active with its accompanying membership.

So I have tried to build this solution but it is just not working, so any advise/direction would be most welcome.

What I have tried:

```
function wp56908_new_order_housekeeping ($order_id)
{
    $args = array(
        'subscriptions_per_page' => -1,
        'customer_id'            => get_current_user_id(),
    );

    $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions($args);

    foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
        $s_order_id = method_exists( $subscription, 'get_parent_id' ) ? $subscription->get_parent_id() : $subscription->order->id;
        if ($s_order_id != $order_id) {
            $cancel_note = 'Customer purchased new subscription in order #' . $order_id;
            $subscription->update_status( 'cancelled', $cancel_note );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'wp56908_new_order_housekeeping',  10, 1  );
```

Comment: What about if you set the subscription status to expired?  What exactly is not working?

Comment: @AndrewSchultz - The code doesn't cancel any of the other subscriptions, so the user ends up with multiple subscriptions. No errors are thrown either

Comment: What hook is this function attached to?

Comment: @AndrewSchultz - woocommerce_thankyou

Comment: @JohanRheeder Yes much better with the action hook in your code.

Comment: From what I read in the documentation I think you need to set the subscription to 'expired' rather than 'cancelled' as they have two different results.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz - The issue with this is that it doesnt even trigger the even to change status

Comment: @JohanRheeder I reported a bug with the function wcs_get_subscriptions() in version 2.1.1 which they have since fixed in the latest version.  I bet if you update the plugin to the latest version your issue with be resolved.  Checking my emails they said it would be included in v 2.2.12

Comment: @AndrewSchultz - I dont think its fixed then as I am on 2.2.16

Comment: @JohanRheeder I've added the email I got from WooCommerce support regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the support email I got from WooCommerce regarding the issue with the function `wcs_get_subscriptions()`.

> Thanks for contacting support and report us this issue!
>
> I've tried it in a local install and I confirm that this seems to be a
>   bug! I've already reported it to our development team and a patch
>   should be included in next updates. By now, if you're in a real hurry
>   and want to get it working, you could search for this code (in
>   wcs-functions.php line 483):
>
> // We need to restrict subscriptions to those which contain a certain
>   product/variation if ( ( 0 != $args['product_id'] && is_numeric(
>   $args['product_id'] ) ) || ( 0 != $args['variation_id'] && is_numeric(
>   $args['variation_id'] ) ) ) { $query_args['post__in'] =
>   wcs_get_subscriptions_for_product( array( $args['product_id'],
>   $args['variation_id'] ) ); }
>
> And replace it with something like:
>
> // We need to restrict subscriptions to those which contain a certain
>   product/variation if ( ( 0 != $args['product_id'] && is_numeric(
>   $args['product_id'] ) ) || ( 0 != $args['variation_id'] && is_numeric(
>   $args['variation_id'] ) ) ) { $prod_args = array( $args['product_id'],
>   $args['variation_id'] ); $prod_args = array_filter($prod_args,
>   function($prod_args) { return ($prod_args !== 0);  });
>   $query_args['post__in'] = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_product(
>   $prod_args ); }
>
> Please take in mind that this is not the ideal solution because you'll
>   be modifying our plugin's code directly and these changes can be lost
>   after updating, but if you feel comfortable with code and want to take
>   the risk as a temporary workaround until we add the proper patch in
>   our plugin, you can do it. ;)
>
> Let me know if you need any help with this!
>
> Thanks, Bernat

Answer (score 0):

There's a new setting in the WC Subscriptions plugin which lets you limit to one active subscription. You can find more information here: [https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/store-manager-guide/#:~:text=Limit%20subscriptions,the%20subscription%20from%20the%20dropdown](https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/store-manager-guide/#:%7E:text=Limit%20subscriptions,the%20subscription%20from%20the%20dropdown).

The end user will get the message:
“You have a subscription to this product. Choosing a new subscription will replace your existing subscription.”