# How to cancel previous WooCommerce subscription automatically when new subscription is purchased?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm building a membership site where users must only have one active subscription at a time. I would like that on a purchase of any new subscription/product all other subscriptions to be cancelled/expired and all associated membership deleted/cancelled. Only the latest subscription should remain active with its accompanying membership.

I cannot/don't want to use the built-in function to limit subscriptions for several reasons.

Is there any way that on the thank you page, a snipped loops in all active subscriptions from current user and cancel/expire them, except for the one that has been just bought?

I've checked this post which looks similar but no real solution was provided ([WooCommerce Subscriptions - Only Allow user one active subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436904/woocommerce-subscriptions-only-allow-user-one-active-subscription))

Thanks a lot for your help

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto-answering as I've managed to solve my issue with the help of other SO posts.

Basically I'm getting all active subscriptions by descending ID and set a counter inside my loop. If it loops more than once then it sets the status of the subscription to cancelled. I hooked this in the thank you page to be sure it fires only when the payment has been made...

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'edf_cancel_previous_active_subscription' );
function edf_cancel_previous_active_subscription() {

    $no_of_loops = 0;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Get all customer subscriptions
    $args = array(
        'subscription_status'       => 'active', 
        'subscriptions_per_page'    => -1,
        'customer_id'               => $user_id, 
        'orderby'                   => 'ID', 
        'order'                     => 'DESC'
    );
    $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions($args);

    // Going through each current customer subscriptions
    foreach ( $subscriptions as $subscription ) {
        $no_of_loops = $no_of_loops + 1;

        if ($no_of_loops > 1){
            $subscription->update_status( 'cancelled' );
        } 
    }
}
```

Not sure whether this is the "Wordpress/WooCommerce" way of doing it but I brought my other programming languages experience with me for this one. If someone has a better idea, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code mentioned below as it cancels all subscriptions if a new user registers though the mentioned code works fine for existing users but when a new user registers all subscriptions of all users will be cancelled
Hence I have developed code as

```
    function edf_cancel_previous_active_subscription() {
    
        $no_of_loops = 0;
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
       
        // If is an existing user
        if($user_id!=0)
        {
        $args = array(
            'subscription_status'       => 'active', 
            'subscriptions_per_page'    => -1,
            'customer_id'               => $user_id, 
            'orderby'                   => 'ID', 
            'order'                     => 'DESC'
        );
        $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions($args);
        // Going through each current customer subscriptions
         foreach ( $subscriptions as $subscription ) {
             $no_of_loops = $no_of_loops + 1;
//Cancel previous subscription of user applying for new subscription
             if ($no_of_loops = 1) {
                 $subscription->update_status( 'pending-cancel' );
             }
         }
     }
    }
//when checkout is in progress previous subscriptions will be cancelled and after successful checkout the subscription for which checkout process was initiated becomes active
    add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_process', 'edf_cancel_previous_active_subscription');
```

Comment: This one exactly worked for me.. Thanks for this